# How to connect (which enum) wih zeromq lot of short sending processes and one long running which only receives

Tags: python, c++, message-queue, zeromq

I need to connect one always running ( in loop ) program which only receives messages from lot of other short running ( read from db, do something simple, pack and send message and die ).
I am using Zeromq like glue between on long and lot of short processes ( long is in c++, short are in python).
Which enum to use on which side ?
At the moment I am using fro python processes

```
socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
```

and for C++

```
zmq::socket_t socket (context, ZMQ_PULL);
```

In every python process I open connection with zeromq over tcp, send message and close (c++ does not send any response to python processes).

( I can post rest of code but it only sends and receives like in example)

Comment: It's not clear what your question is; is there a problem with what you are currently doing?

Comment: @chepner I don't have experience with zeromq, I need from handlers for rest (python, which ends quickly) to send message to c++ long running(loop) process, is PUSH / PULL appropriate combination for this.

Comment: Yes, `PUSH/PULL` is fine for this scenario.